# Attribute error while importing boto3 using python3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to use aws rekognition client using boto3 on my raspberry pi, have successfully installed aws cli and have configured it also. But when i execute the following code avaialbe in aws blog,

```
import boto3

def detect_labels_local_file(photo):


    client=boto3.client('rekognition')

    with open(photo, 'rb') as image:
        response = client.detect_labels(Image={'Bytes': image.read()})

    print('Detected labels in ' + photo)    
    for label in response['Labels']:
        print (label['Name'] + ' : ' + str(label['Confidence']))

    return len(response['Labels'])

def main():
    photo='photo'

    label_count=detect_labels_local_file(photo)
    print("Labels detected: " + str(label_count))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error :

```
  import boto3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 28, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 25, in <module>
    from botocore.exceptions import MD5UnavailableError
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/exceptions.py", line 99, in <module>
    class SSLError(ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.SSLError):
AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'exceptions
```

Please help me solve it , or tell me what i'm doing wrong . Note :  I'm using python 3.7.3 .

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/) should help to explain it.

You will now need to include this dependency yourself as it is no longer bundled with boto3.

For you Raspberry Pi running the following should be sufficient

```
pip install requests
```

Then add `import requests` to your py script

Comment: i read the blog post, but i'm still not clear what do i need to do; just import requests also before boto3? I tried that but the error still exits.

Comment: Basically run `pip install requests` on your host. Then add `import requests` to top of your script

Comment: It didn't work bro, still getting the same error, but in my ubuntu pc it works fine. So i'm changing systems to work with it.